# Submit data from PHP to HTML

Tags: php

I have created a search page on PHP that searches for user from database. After the results are retrieved, i have created a view button that would display profile information of that user in HTML page. I am not quite sure how to send information from PHP to HTML. Below is the code for your reference. I would appreciate if someone could shed some light on this.

**retrieve.php**

```html
<?php

 echo "<body style='background-color:#DCDCDC'>";
// echo '<img src="back to school.jpg'. $row['filename'] .'" style="width:600px; height:300px;" alt="" /><br />';
include ("account.php");
( $dbh = mysql_connect( $hostname, $username, $password ))
    or die ( "unable to connect to MYSQL database" );
mysql_select_db( $project );


if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM BPi_registration ";

    $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);

    $sql .= "WHERE first_name= '{$search_term}'";

    $sql .= " OR last_name= '{$search_term}'";
    $query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}



?>



<html>  
<head>  
<title>Jon</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<form name="search_form" method="POST" action="retrieve.php">  
<table width="599" border="2">  
<tr>  
<th>Search Here

<input type ="text" name ="search_box" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Find Users">

</tr>  
</table>  
</form>  


<table width="600" border="2">  
<tr>  
<th width="91"> <div align="center">First Name </div></th>  
<th width="98"> <div align="center">Last Name </div></th>  
<th width="198"> <div align="center">Email </div></th>  
<th width="97"> <div align="center">City </div></th>  
<th width="97"> <div align="center">State </div></th>  
<th width="59"> <div align="center">Country </div></th>   
<th width="59"> <div align="center">View </div></th>   


<tr>


<?php  if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){ ?>



<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['first_name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['last_name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['address_city'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['address_state'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['address_country'];?></td>
<td><a href="handler.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><input type="button" value="view"/> </a><td>

  
 
<tr>

<?php }} ?>

</table>
```

**handler.php**

```html
<?php
$userid = $_GET['id'];


?>
```

Comment: You are already `send information from PHP to HTML`, here `<?php echo $row['first_name'];?>` and other places.

Comment: @chris85 so "retrieve.php" would simply perform search from database table. Once the search is performed and when i click on "view" i am directed to "handler.php?id=19" where "id" is primary key. I want to use that primary from handler.php to display data on another HTML page.

Comment: So do another query on that other page that pulls the data based on parameter.

Comment: @chris85 okay let me try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).

*** edits ***

In this part you nested a button inside a tag.

```
<td><a href="handler.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><input type="button" value="view"/> </a><td>
```

Try just adding text there, like:

```
<td><a href="handler.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">View</a><td>
```

This will appear as clickable text "View" in blue font color and will redirect to hander.php .

Hope that helps.

Comment: I edited my answer for you. Sorry did not read your question carefully at first. But maybe PHP Session will help you in the future. :D

Comment: Yes i am able to go to handler.php. But from there if i wish to go to HTML page, do i jst create another query or is there any other way. I am here to know all possible ways i can redirect "handler.php" to another HTML page. Sorry i do not have enough reputation to upvote your answer

Comment: Ah, you can use header (http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). In your hander.php add code like this:
`header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;`

After `$userid = $_GET['id'];`

Comment: this helps appreciated